# Creating a dropdown search in WP using custom field values

Tags: wordpress, search, field

I'm hoping someone is able to help me.  I have a small news site that is built on Wordpress, which covers news from all over Europe.  We use Wordpress categories to split up our news sections (Music, Features etc..), so to seperate country specific content,  I have setup the custom field "Country".    In the add post screen, an editor would select a country from the list which equals the custom field value.

What I'd like to do now is have a dropdown search on the homepage which contains the list of countries that we cover (as well as a left aligned 16x16 flag image).   The default wordpress search does not allow me to have a dropdown list and requires something to be manually typed in the search box.  What I'd ideally like is for the user to have to select a country from the dropdown list which would then query the posts with that country value.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, that's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response :)  I've gone as far as creating the HTML for the dropdown but I have no clue as to how to link that to the Wordpress search.php - Would I need a custom search page altogether?